# Why we can use height property instead of max-height property in animated accordion?

Tags: javascript, html, css

why in this code I can use height instead of max-height and so it still works?
and the second question is: why we have to set the overflow property to hidden when the height is zero.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_animate
it is the original code above.

```js
 
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.height){
          panel.style.height = null;
        } else {
         panel.style.height = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
       });
     }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .active, .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Animated Accordion</h2>
    <p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>
    <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
     eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
     <div class="panel">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
     <div class="panel">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do 
    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad 
    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip 
    ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: "why in this code I can use height instead of max-height and so it still works?" why do you expect it shouldn't? What did you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: "and the second question is" please, one question per post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `max-height` - allow element to be smaller than set value. E.g. `height: 20px; max-height: 30px;` -> element is 20px height. 
   When you apply `height` you do not allow any other size of element than the one you set. That's why it's working fine with `max-height` and `height`.
   Check [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)
2. `overflow:hidden; height: 0;` is required because even if you set height smaller than content, this content will still be visible out of box boundaries. Setting `overflow: hidden` would hide content of element that exceeds height.

Comment: great explanation

Comment: Sorry sir, would you mind explaining more your words about height and max-height? Thanks.

Comment: @Septic.S.H Please read documentation about it and compare two values. One sets actual height and another sets upper limit for it

Comment: Got it. In this code, it doesn't matter we use height or max-height, true?

Comment: @Septic.S.H Yes, it does not matter

Comment: @Septic.S.H Accept answer if it satisfies your needs

Comment: Ok.Thanks a lot.